# C++ two-phase path-compression quick-union union find over indices

Tags: c++, union-find

This is my first C++ class, implementing union find. I’ve tested the implementation very shoddily by checking that unifying two points connects them, and that works. I did a first draft in Python and translated it to C++. I use two buffers to keep track of the traversed items instead of creating a vector each time. Unfortunately I can’t use `size_type` for the sizes that are used for vectors because that’d require a recursive type. I named the method `unify` since `union` is a keyword in C++. I have not tested for performance. I mostly did this by skimming reference materials, tutorials, and examples.

Is this code easy to read, correct, performant, idiomatic, or is there befuddling syntax, bugs, bottlenecks, idiosyncrasies?

```cc
#include <vector>
#include <optional>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

class UnionFind {
    std::vector<std::optional<std::size_t>> parents;
    std::vector<std::size_t> crumbs_buf_a;
    std::vector<std::size_t> crumbs_buf_b;
    std::size_t group_count;
    
    std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> find_roots(std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
        std::size_t current;
        std::optional<std::size_t> next;
        crumbs_buf_a[0] = a;
        current = a;
        int i;
        for (i = 1; (next = parents[current]); i++) {
            current = *next;
            crumbs_buf_a[i] = current;
        }
        crumbs_buf_b[0] = b;
        current = b;
        int j;
        for (j = 1; (next = parents[current]); j++) {
            current = *next;
            crumbs_buf_b[j] = current;
        }
        return {i, j};
    }
    
    public:
    UnionFind(std::size_t count) {
        std::optional<std::size_t> nothing = {};
        parents.resize(count, nothing);
        crumbs_buf_a.resize(count, 0);
        crumbs_buf_b.resize(count, 0);
        group_count = count;
    }
    
    bool unify(std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
        auto [depth_a, depth_b] = find_roots(a, b);
        auto root_a = crumbs_buf_a[depth_a - 1];
        auto root_b = crumbs_buf_b[depth_b - 1];
        if (root_a != root_b) {
            if (depth_a > depth_b)
                for (std::size_t i = 0; i < depth_a; i++)
                    parents[crumbs_buf_a[i]] = root_b;
            else
                for (std::size_t i = 0; i < depth_b; i++)
                    parents[crumbs_buf_b[i]] = root_a;
            group_count--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    std::size_t find(std::size_t a) {
        auto current = a;
        std::optional<std::size_t> next;
        while ((next = parents[current]))
            current = *next;
        return current;
    }
    
    bool connected(std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
        return find(a) == find(b);
    }
    
    std::size_t get_group_count() {
        return group_count;
    }
    
    void extend(std::size_t additional = 1) {
        std::optional<std::size_t> nothing = {};
        parents.resize(parents.size() + additional, nothing);
        crumbs_buf_a.resize(crumbs_buf_a.size() + additional, 0);
        crumbs_buf_b.resize(crumbs_buf_b.size() + additional, 0);
        group_count += additional;
    }
};
```

I used this code to do rudimentary tests:

```cc
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#define COUNT 100

int main() {
    UnionFind uf(COUNT);
    std::vector<std::size_t> indices;
    indices.reserve(COUNT);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        indices.push_back(i);
    // mostly copied from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle example
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), g);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < COUNT - 1; i++) {
        std::size_t ix_1 = indices[i];
        std::size_t ix_2 = indices[i + 1];
        uf.unify(ix_1, ix_2);
        assert(uf.connected(ix_1, ix_2));
        std::cout << ix_1 << ", " << ix_2 << '\n';
    }
    assert(uf.get_group_count() == 1);
}
```

Comment: Consider adding your test too, for added documentation and facilitating our own testsing.

Comment: This is unusual, typically the path-compression is in `find`. There are variants that do it in `union` however. Which variant is this supposed to be? Or is it just something fairly arbitrary?

Comment: It arose from a misunderstanding. I have now learned that this is weird.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, it seems cumbersome.

First, using a `std::size_t` instead of a `std::optional<std::size_t>`, and making the roots their own parent, would half the needed memory.

Next, throwing away the additional buffers will reduce it to a third of that.

The interface need not change for that.

Rewriting the algorithm is simple enough:

```
// Internal use and if the structure is read-only
FindRoot (array, node):
    while array[node] != node:
        node = array[node]
    return node
// Internal use only
CompressPath (array, node, root):
    while array[node] != node:
        (node, array[node]) = (array[node], root)
    array[node] = root

// For finding pass just one node
Unify (array, nodes):
    root = array.size
    foreach node in nodes:
        root = min(root, FindRoot(array, node))
    foreach node in nodes:
        CompressPath(array, node, root)
    return root

CompressAllPaths(array):
    for node = 0; node < array.size; ++node:
        array[node] = array[array[node]]
```

Still, while it is good for amortized cost, it is terrible for worst case. For that, more intelligence in picking the new root is needed, wikipedia has a good overview.

---

Regarding your code:

1. Only pass an element to `.resize()` if default-constructing is undesirable.
2. Avoid the preprocessor, a constexpr constant is generally better.

Comment: Which variant of union-find is this? It's still something unusual

Comment: Not really unusual. FindRoot is the same as yours, roots are marked by self-reference instead of absent parent, and the crumbs are replaced by a second trace of the path.

Comment: Well, not mine but OPs.. and doing a second trace is not unusual, but doing path-compression in `unify` instead of in `find` is unusual. There is a variant described by Norbert Blum that works that way (I don't know if it works *this* specific way, but it does have path-compression in `unify`), but it's not what you'll typically see.

Comment: @harold unify is the only one which should be public, just call with a single node... Recursion in find to compress the path would risk stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok I don't feel like that is a reply to anything I wrote, but I'll take it under advisement. I mean, the usual way to implement union-find, which neither OP nor your code implements, is using path-compression *in `find`*, and then `unify` doesn't need to do it.

Comment: Yes, well, here find is replaced by unify.

Comment: So is this a real variant or did you just come up with it on the spot?

Comment: @harold It's not much different from the standard non-recursive variant, certainly not enough for its own name.

Comment: Well, it's confusing and non-standard.